# Hover to solid background?

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, mouseenter

I am trying to achieve this effect on my website and am stumped on how to do it.  My goal is to have an image that when you mouse over it a solid color (with like an opacity of .8) and an icon(and/or text) are displayed on top.
Note: My images are also set up to be responsive, so I'm not sure if this will create a problem or not.
EXAMPLE>>If you click the link below, and then the computer on the left, and then scroll to the bottom where there are 9 circles that have hover effects which is similar to my goal.
http://themeforest.net/item/strand-one-page-parallax-bootstrap-template/full_screen_preview/5445825

Any direction, tutorials, advice would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like a job for [jQuery.hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).  Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Yeah, I'm still kind of new to the scene so I wasn't sure what would be best.  I played around with .mouseenter and .fadeIn, but I'm kind of confused on how i need to structure the html and what I need to even put in there.

Comment: @Kobaine Did you try any of the fiddles referenced in my answer? I would have put the code in my answer but that would make quite a long answer. Have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't really use javascript to do this. Here is a bare bones example of a solution. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zujBc

This is the key concept:

```
.container:hover .overlay-color {
    opacity:.5;
}
```

Getting the color overlay container to be 100% height might be tricky in some IE versions. Position is everything.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options for this kind of effect, and it may depend on your specific use-case.
You can adopt a gracefully-degraded CSS-only that animates the `opacity` of the element using CSS3 property `transition`. Which will only animate in supporting browsers, modern browsers such as IE9+ and chrome, FF, etc.

-> See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yVwe6/)

Otherwise you will have to use a JavaScript library such as jQuery. To apply `.fadeToggle()` or `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` in combination with a `.hover()` or `.mouseenter()` and `.mouseleave()`. This should work cross-browser so long as I think you choose a jQuery library less than v2 in which older IE browser support is dropped. (Haven't tested this). A JS solution would also allow you to easily change the animation be using `.slideToggle` or `.show(500)` instead, or other more varied animations using `$(element).animate({'opacity': 1, 'height' : 100%'}, slow);` and the vice-versa.

So a JS solution using identical markup would be something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9cE67/1/).

jQuery References:

- [.fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/)
- [.slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)
- [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)
- [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)